# Save matplotlib graph as full screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a code that draws a figure by coordinates, the problem is that when I try to save it as PNG, it gets distorted and goes wrong, while when I show it on the screen, the figure turns out very well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
profile = [['profile12'  , 1.118,  0.457,  0.125,  0.078,  0.138]]
for j in range(len(profile)):   

    fig = plt.figure()
    xi_down = 0
    yi_down = 0
    xf_down = profile[j][2]*1000
    yf_down = 0

    xi_up = 0
    yi_up = profile[j][1]*1000
    xf_up = profile[j][2]*1000
    yf_up = profile[j][1]*1000

    xi_mid = profile[j][2]/2*1000
    yi_mid = 0
    xf_mid = profile[j][2]/2*1000
    yf_mid = profile[j][1]*1000

    plt.plot((xi_down, xf_down), (yi_down, yf_down), linewidth = profile[j][3]*1000, color = 'slategrey')
    plt.plot((xi_up, xf_up), (yi_up, yf_up), linewidth = profile[j][3]*1000, color = 'slategrey')
    plt.plot((xi_mid, xf_mid), (yi_mid, yf_mid), linewidth = profile[j][4]*1000, color = 'slategrey')

    plt.title('profile')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.grid(True, linewidth = 0.5, color = 'silver')

    plt.ylim(-700, 1800)

    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()    
    mng.window.showMaximized()

    fig = plt.gcf()    
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig('a.png')
```

**I have noticed that the figure turns out very well as long as I maximize it in the screen output**, that's why, by code, I got it to always show me maximized, **the problem is when I save it as png.**

Is there a solution that can work for this type of case? Greetings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you tweak your created figure a bit:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 25), dpi=100)

# [snipp rest of code]

fig.savefig('a.png' )
```

you'll get:

[image: bigger pic]

You set the figures size in inches this way and the resolution. See [plt.figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figure) documentation.

Tweak the values to your liking....